# PdfReadWarning: impossible to decode XFormObject

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using PyPDF2 to extract fields of data from PDF documents.
Previously, I had been reading files with code below

```
with open(filepath, mode='rb') as f:
   pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
   num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
   ....
   for i in range(num_pages): 
      page = pdf.pages[i].extract_text()
      ....
```

I've run this code numerous times on my PDFs and have only gotten a warning regarding Xref table not zero-indexed. Out of nowhere, I started getting impossible to decode XFormObject warnings. Neither my PDFs nor the way I process pages via the for loop above has changed.

Below are variations I have tried all end with the same warnings.

```
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(filepath)
num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
   ....
```

```
with open(filepath, mode='rb') as f:
   pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(f)
   num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
```

Any idea what could be causing the warnings? Alternatively, is there a way to catch warnings only sent from PyPDF2? I'd prefer to not have to silence all warnings since I've created some of my own for users in the future.

Comment: Did you upgrade PyPDF2? Which version has the issue and which one doesn't?

Comment: warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=PyPDF2.errors.PdfReadWarning) might do the trick for you. (I'm hiking, I can't check right now)

Comment: @MartinThoma I've been learning to use a virtual environment and didn't realize I could save the version of PyPDF2 I was using. It looks like the warning occurs more often starting in 2.4 and above. I've changed my reqs to use 2.3.1 and used the warning filter you suggested to catch stragglers. Thank you for your help!